# Design pattern for managing beans in jsp, servlet

Tags: jsp, design-patterns, servlets

I am involved in a jsp/servlet application. The application stores objects needed in session or request. However the same object can be injected into session or request in multiple locations. In other words, instead of writing

```
HomeBean homeBean = (HomeBean) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("homeBean");
```

I will write

```
HomeBean homeBean = BeanStore.getHomeBean();
```

Am I overthinking or overdesigning ?

Comment: See it's funny because you're Ender, talking about Bean.

Comment: How does a static `BeanStore` implementation solve the problem?

Comment: Bad example BeanStore.getCurrentInstance().getHomeBean ... BeanStore is thread local and created in a filter.

Comment: Yep, I am stuck in a world of jdbc and scriptlet.. I am trying to find Bean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some frameworks like [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) or [cdi](/questions/tagged/cdi) you can inject session or even some session attribute directly to your business component, something like:

```
@Inject
private HomeBean homeBean;
```

Also instead of polluting your code with HTTP session access code just fetch the object once and pass it where needed. It will make reading and testing easier.

Note that your `BeanStore.getHomeBean()` is really hard to write correctly if you really don't want to pass `HttpSession` directly. Servlet filters and `ThreadLocal`, here I come! Not to mention I find such static "factory" quite ugly.

---

Side note, in:

```
request.getSession(false).getAttribute("homeBean")
```

`request.getSession(false)` will often return `null`, leaving you with nasty `NullPointerException`. Prefer `true` or no parameters at all in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The architect does not want me to use spring, jsf or any other framework so I am stuck with implementing something for myself. I was thinking of using ThreadLocal since I have already such an object.